# How do I plug a leak in my refrigerator's water fountain casing?

Tags: leak, refrigerator, sealing

We seem to have developed a slow water leak at the bottom right edge of the casing for the water dispenser in the left door of our GE refrigerator. This is causing water to drip slowly along the front face of the door all the way down to the floor. The dripping water is stagnating on the wooden floor causing the wood to slowly warp. Here are some pictures showing this.

[image: Location of leak]
[image: Front face of fridge showing streak]

How can I stop this leak?

**-- update --**

The leak seems to be because of water under the drip tray, but this water is not overflowing -- there has always been a small amount of water stagnating under the tray for the last 4 years without this leakage.

Including picture of model number.
[image: Model/serial number]

Comment: Is leak from the drip tray at the bottom overflowing? If not, and the water is leaking from behind the plastic of the dispenser, you have a leak behind the door. This is known it the trade as 'very bad' or 'difficult to repair.' Please let us know the answer, and the model number of the fridge. If the leak is inside of the door, some part of the door is coming off, difficulty varies by model.

Comment: @SomeGuy I updated the question with the model#. Does this give you any additional info by chance?

Comment: Turns out this is a leak in the water supply somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause may be the closure flap in the ice hopper delivery chute. There is a spring-loaded flap up there which opens when you actuate the dispensing lever. Make sure it is closing all the way and sealing (there is a foam seal on the "ice" side of the flap, check it for damage) or the ice in the bottom of the hopper can melt and drip down into the tray. Also ice sometimes gets trapped in the chute and does not fall all the way down into your container, it then melts and drips into the tray.

Shine a flashlight up into the chute and check it out.

Comment: It turns out it was not this, but actually a leak in the water line somewhere :-/